# What happens when I run `su` as root?

Tags: root, su

If I run `su` repeatedly as root (yea, why would anyone want to do that? :), I have to `exit` once for each time I ran `su` in order to get back to the regular user. What's happening?

```
user@computer:~$ su
Password: 
root@computer:/home/user# su
root@computer:/home/user# su
root@computer:/home/user# exit
exit
root@computer:/home/user# exit
exit
root@computer:/home/user# exit
exit
user@computer:~$
```

Comment: Check your `auth.log` file. A new session will be opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are spawning a new shell each time you execute `su`.  If the root user has `bash` set as the login shell, you will see an increasing number of `bash` processes each time you `su`

```
ps aux | grep bash
```

Each `exit` terminates one shell and returns you to the shell in which you (last) executed `su`.

This has nothing to do with executing `su` as root, except for the convenience of being able to do it repeatedly without entering credentials.  You'd get the same result `su`ing to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply starting a new subshell as `root`. There is no difference to using `su <yourusername>` and `su <yourusername>`. You will have to exit those too in order to get back to the "original" user.